# How and where can I organize a North Korea DMZ tour if I'm staying in Seoul?

Tags: south-korea, north-korea

My friends and I are interested in the DMZ, and we are looking to spend a day trip there. I understand that there are Saturday tours, but there aren't a lot of details around regarding that.

How can we take a day tour to the North Korea DMZ?